# Ruby-on-rails 4 slow performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I've seen significant performance problems after upgrading to Rails.

I've recently upgraded my project from Rails 2 and Ruby 1.8 to Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0. Reading around on the internet, I understand that upgrading should provide excellent performance improvement (up to 30%) out of the box. Unfortunately, I've found that the performance is a lot worse in some cases e.g. some reports that were previously taking around 20 seconds, now take 40 seconds.

I've seen some posts that suggest Garbage Collection may be the issue. After using some recommended settings, I've found that some of the longer reports are actually shorter, but the short reports are still much worse.

As part of the upgrade, I've moved over to unobtrusive javascript for the view rendering, but this doesn't seem to contribute to performance issues - most of the time is being spent in the model.

Does anybody know if I'm missing some configuration 'gotchas'? Did anybody else have performance problems as a result of the upgrade?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a git url. It is probably project specific. I have used rails 2, 3, and 4 and I haven't noticed that much speed performance, and not negative performance. You probably haven't fully optimized or properly converted your project.

Comment: Do you use [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/)?

Comment: Shrav, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I can't post the code. However, I haven't taken any steps to optimize the code. Do you mean in terms of ruby compilation etc?

Comment: user2422869, no I don't

Comment: @MattThomas did you figure anything out, finally? Its been long, but recently I made this kind of an upgrade, and I'm noticing that everything is slower! (3.2 -> 4 -> 4.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably always going to be edge cases in upgrades, where certain types of operation run slower and other faster. It would probably be best to just follow regular performance tuning techniques and use tools such as the Oink gem and NewRelic to look analyse the slowest issues.

To be rigorous it's usually best to gather as much performance profiling data prior to the upgrade as possible so you can then tell whether a particular operation is suffering from higher memory consumption, more/slower garbage collection, different generated SQL (from an activerecord upgrade), more objects being created. With post-upgrade profiling it can be difficult to put the data in context so you can tell if the creation of 30 Post objects is normal for a given action, for example.

With respect to eager loading, we found bullet to be a very useful gem for getting the right level. You're right that it's not necessarily a Rails 3/4 issue, of course.

Another pain point for us has also been to not only reduce the number of queries but to be careful about whether we really need to create an object. You can sometimes get away with just retrieving the data for display without creating the object. Furthermore, we are now very careful about (for example) implicitly running:

```
select * from books where client_id = 1 order by name
```

... in order to create a dropdown of book names, when we could:

```
select id, name from books where client_id = 1 order by name
```

It is hugely more efficient on the Rails side, even if the difference in sometimes marginal on the database side (100ms vs 20ms on the database, but 2000ms vs 500ms on the Rails side).

Again, possibly not Rails 3/4 relevant unless there is a quirk in Rails 4 that makes it even less efficient, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks David. I have installed the RubyProf profiler. In addition to running in Debug mode, it tells me that a lot of CPU time is used on looping through model code and a lot of queries are generated. I've taken some steps to reduce the total queries by using eager loading. While it reduces the queries, I'm still not seeing much improvement.

Comment: It also doesn't explain why Rails is working slower out of the box. But maybe you're right, I should try to go back to an older version and obtain timings / profile results

Comment: That's some really good advice David, I haven't heard of Bullet, but I will look to get it. Interesting about only returning what you need too. Using ActiveRecord, all columns are retrieved in most cases currently.

Comment: Yes, it's a common performance problem with ORM architecture, but goes beyond database-level efficiency. I think that the major issues with performance problems are accurate measurement, valid comparisons, and focusing on the issues that show the greatest possible benefits-to-efforts ratio.

Comment: I hadn't tried this idea of selecting only specific attributes until now, but it seems like a good idea. By default, ActiveRecord retrieves all columns, but I want to point out that you can do something like this, to limit it to the columns you want:  record = Record.find(:first, :select => 'id,report_date', :conditions => ['id=?', 1])  #<Record id: 1, report_date: "2013-02-02">  Then you can use ORM to access the selected columns as usual, only the unselected columns will cause a missing attribute error.