# Rails 4.1 app running on apache - passenger is very very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've deployed a rails 4.1 app on digitalocean's basic $5 vps.

```
This is the link : http://107.170.188.209/
```

( sorry, havent linked the domain name yet )

The stack: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, apache, passenger, mysql

It is very slow, and I have no idea why.

Even when tried with webrick, speed is the same.

How can I find out why it is slow, and how to fix it?

Comment: Doesn't look "very very slow" to me. However some pictures are not showing.

Answer (score -1):

You could talk with you provider to see if they are having speed problems. Check for javascript import errors, for example, I see and error loading a font and a javascript. Seems Rails 4 is having speed performances, please check this link: [Ruby-on-rails 4 slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321392/ruby-on-rails-4-slow-performance)